# Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/prop-types/index.js with rollup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, storybook, rollup

I'm having the following error with rollup when I try rollup -c:

[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/prop-types/index.js, imported by node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome/index.es.js

And I'm digging and I'cant figured out the problem.
Actually this happen with any library I have installed in my project it says the same: 'default' is not exported by node_modules etc... by [name the library].

This is the rollup.config.js:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import png from '@rollup/plugin-image'

export default [
    {
        input: './src/components/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.ts',
                format: 'cjs',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/index.es.ts',
                format: 'es',
                exports: 'named',
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            postcss({
                plugins: [],
                minimize: true,
            }),
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
            }),
            external(),
            resolve(),
            png(),
            typescript({
                tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
                declaration: true,
                declarationDir: 'dist',
            }),
        ]
    }
]
```

tsconfig.json

```
<pre>
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    
    "rootDir": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

</pre>
```